# Concatenate unique cell values in every row

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

[image: Example]

[image: Result]

How can I concatenate unique cell values in every row to adapt in the code below. Removing duplicate values in a cell. Result after macro is the second image.

```
Sub Concatenar()

Dim myRange As Range
Dim c As Long
Dim r As Long
Dim txt As String
Set myRange = Application.InputBox("Selecione a primeira e a última célula:", Type:=8)
For r = 1 To myRange.Rows.Count
    For c = 1 To myRange.Columns.Count
        If myRange(r, c).Text <> "" Then
             txt = txt & myRange(r, c).Text & vbLf
        End If
    Next
      If Right(txt, 1) = vbLf Then
       txt = Left(txt, Len(txt) - 1)
    End If
    myRange(r, 1) = txt
    txt = ""
Next
Range(myRange(1, 2), myRange(1, myRange.Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Delete
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does what you want, I believe. It pastes/tranposes the values to a temporary workbook, uses `RemoveDuplicates` to trim them down, and `Join` to munge them all together. It then pastes the munged values back into column A of the original workbook and deletes the other columns.

Because of the destructive nature of this code, you must test it on a copy of your data:

```
Sub CrazyPaste()
Dim wsSource As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rngToConcat As Excel.Range
Dim wbTemp As Excel.Workbook
Dim wsPasted As Excel.Worksheet
Dim rngPasted As Excel.Range
Dim i As Long
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Results() As String

Set wsSource = ActiveSheet
Set rngToConcat = wsSource.UsedRange
Set wbTemp = Workbooks.Add
Set wsPasted = wbTemp.Worksheets(1)
wsSource.UsedRange.Copy
wsPasted.Range("A1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
Set rngPasted = wsPasted.UsedRange
ReDim Results(1 To rngPasted.Columns.Count)
For i = 1 To rngPasted.Columns.Count
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(rngPasted.Columns(i)) = 0 Then
        Results(i) = ""
    Else
        rngPasted.Columns(i).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
        LastRow = Cells(wsPasted.Rows.Count, i).End(xlUp).Row
        Results(i) = Replace(Join(Application.Transpose(rngPasted.Columns(i).Resize(LastRow, 1)), vbCrLf), _
                             vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf)
    End If
Next i
With wsSource
    .Range("A1").Resize(i - 1, 1) = Application.Transpose(Results)
    .Range(.Cells(1, 2), .Cells(1, .Columns.Count)).EntireColumn.Delete
    wbTemp.Close False
End With
End Sub
```

In my limited testing, the only situation where this might yield unwanted results is when a cell in the first column is blank, but there's other data in that row. The resulting cell would then start with a blank.

Comment: Thank you, Doug, for your work. I will test it. But a blank cell in first column and other data in same row is very common. I forgot to put this situation in image. And in my real sheet, other columns that don't be concatenated exist.

Comment: Ah well, those are relatively minor changes. Maybe this will be a good start for you.